# Get alert, if radio button in group of options is not checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have placed radio button inside foreach loop based on records  radio button will be  shown with options  yes or  no ,so lets say two records so number of radio buttons with options yes or no will be 4

```
for record1 then rule no 1 from table //

<input type="radio" id="1" class="terms_"/>Yes
<input type="radio" id="2" class="terms_"/>No  

for record 2  then  rule no 2 from table//

<input type="radio" id="3" class="terms_"/>Yes
<input type="radio" id="4" class="terms_"/>No 

<input type="submit" class="validate" value="Submit"/>
```

so what if I don't select any option yes or no from rule 1 then show alert select (yes /no), again if I don't select any option for rule alert should come please select (yes/no) from rule 2,but in my code I am getting 4 times alert but I want two alerts to show because options are two only.

```
 $(".validate").click(function() {
    $('.terms_').each(function() {
       if (!$(".terms_:checked").val()) {
          alert('Oops,Please select yes or no.');
       }
    });
 });
```

Comment: Use the `length` property: `if ($(".terms_:checked").length === 0) `

Comment: @Rory McCrossan  this also woking ,I am getting 4 alert  but I want two alert either yes or no based on different options from table records

Comment: In that case you need to put a containing element around each group of radios and loop over that, selecting only the radio elements within the container

Comment: will you please code it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add *name* attribute to the radio buttons to make group for them, then check the length to show the message:

```js
$(".validate").click(function(){
  var len = $('[name=rule1]:checked, [name=rule2]:checked').length;
  if (len <= 1)  {
    alert('Oops,Please select yes or no.'); 
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <div>
    <label>Rule 1</label>
    <input type="radio" id="1" name="rule1" class="terms_"/>Yes
    <input type="radio" id="2" name="rule1" class="terms_"/>No 
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Rule 2</label>
    <input type="radio" id="3" name="rule2" class="terms_"/>Yes
    <input type="radio" id="4" name="rule2" class="terms_"/>No 
  </div>

  <input type="submit" class="validate" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```